# Can you use a for loop to create array names?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am pulling data from a database and I want to create array names on the fly.....group1, group2...etc using a for loop. I wonder if this is possible at all? The code below obviously doesn't work and I'm only including it to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
 <?php
    for ($i=1; $i <=40; $i++){  
    $group.$i = [];
}
?>
```

Comment: If you were wanting to do dynamically created variables, you can use `variable variables` as shown in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not so much "array names" that you are looking for as a much as a nested array.  `$group[$i]` would give you a nested array. eg

```
for ($i=1; $i <=40; $i++){  
    $group[$i] = [];
}

$group[1][] = 'foo';
echo $group[1][0];
// prints: foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? This works 100%

```
// $result = $conn->query($sql);

$i = 0;
$all = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $i++;

    $arr[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $arr[$i]['firstname'] = $row['first_name'];
    $arr[$i]['lastname'] = $row['last_name'];

    $all[] = $arr[$i];
}

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($all);
```